# StmCubeIDE Issues with debugging STM32F411CEU6

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, stm32f4

I have ordered the black pill ( STM32F411CEU6, real ones ) to replace my blue pill dev kits that didn't have enough RAM and have had nothing but issues getting it going. I have generated the project using STM32CubeIDE.

I'm using A11, 12, 13 for GPIO output and PB9, 8 for I2C communication, and A10, 11 for my USART device.

I am able to get the st link programmer and software to detect my black pill and debug for a short duration until I enter `MX_GPIO_Init()`

After this the programmer loses communication with the device and prevents me from doing any real programming. Some places I have looked says to try to set the  Sys -> Debug setting to **"Serial Wire"** but this is disabled by default for me and am unable to switch it.

In context of debugging when I do debug in live mode I can see a debug enabled

```
Starting server with the following options:
        Persistent Mode            : Disabled
        Logging Level              : 1
        Listen Port Number         : 61234
        Status Refresh Delay       : 15s
        Verbose Mode               : Disabled
        SWD Debug                  : Enabled
        InitWhile                  : Enabled
```

So the debugging looks like it's set up properly but I just don't understand why it can't call the init for the GPIO from looking at the debug console I get this

```
handle_vCont_c, Failed continue thread
```

which is thrown after entering this function

```
HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);
```

which doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me as I have not seen this before, can someone please help me out setting up this project properly? thanks.

Comment: I should note I have discovered the trick for getting this thing to communicate properly which is to hold down the NRST and boot 0 buttons and then release from the NRST and only hold the boot until the programmer has got a connection. Was the first issue I had which i was able to solve and just wanted to throw it out there so we can rule that one out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The serial wire debug interface is defined for PA13 and PA14. In CubeMx IDE, first set SYS->Debug->Serial Wire. Select another pin for GPIO instead of PA13.

Comment: i'll give that a try and see how it goes.. sounds like a big mistake on my part thanks for the info!